# Error in SQL syntax near STR_TO_DATE

Tags: php, sql

Can someone solve my problem?
With SQL I wrote:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO siswa_baru (NISN, nama, tempat_lahir, tanggal_lahir, alamat, agama, jenis_kelamin, sekolah_asal, nilai_rata) VALUES ("
    .$nisn.",'"
    .$nama.",'"
    .$tempat_lahir."', "
    . " STR_TO_DATE('".$tanggal_lahir."', '%d-%m-%Y'),'"
    .$alamat."','"
    .$agama."','"
    .$jenis_kelamin."','"
    .$sekolah_asal."',"
    .$nilai." )";
```

and the following issue persists:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '','', STR_TO_DATE('', '%d-%m-%Y'),'','','','', )' at line 1

Comment: You are missing single quotes in every parameter like `.$nisn.",'".$nama.",'"`  it should be like `.$nisn.",'".$nama."','"`

Comment: look for the `tanggal_lahir` variable I guess it is not in `'%d-%m-%Y'` format.

Comment: Extra `,` before `$nilai`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO siswa_baru (NISN, nama, tempat_lahir, tanggal_lahir, alamat, agama, jenis_kelamin, sekolah_asal, nilai_rata) VALUES ("
'.$nisn."','"
.$nama."','"
.$tempat_lahir."','"
. " STR_TO_DATE('".$tanggal_lahir."', '%d-%m-%Y'),'"'
.$alamat."','"
.$agama."','"
.$jenis_kelamin."','"
.$sekolah_asal."','"
.$nilai."')";
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but did all values should be given a single quote? because nisn is an integer not character

Comment: So dont include single quote for integer value